# How to format composition functions in python?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

When I use composition functions Such as Collatz(MerrenianPrime(Number))
I get the error of:

```
'Merrenian=2**PrimeCount(Number)-1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'NoneType.'
```

How would I resolve this?

This is my code:

```
def MerrenianPrime(Number):
    Merrenian=2**Prime.PrimeCount(Number)-1 #PrimeCount=nth Prime and this is where I get an error                                               
    if Prime.isPrime(Merrenian)==True: #isPrime function checks primality of number
        print "the prime number",Merrenian,"was found"
    else:
        print Merrenian,"is not prime."
```

thanks!

Comment: And what is `Prime.PrimeCount(Number)` here? It returns `None`. You'll need to share the code with us to help you.

Comment: You need to `return` values, not `print` them, if you want to use a return value elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The `Prime.PrimeCount()` callable returns `None` (usually because you didn't include a `return` statement).

Fix that method to return a numeric value instead.